# Normalized distance between 3d/2d points

Tags: math, 3d, computer-vision, kinect, distance

I have a project using 3d facial feature points from kinect sensor. I need to calculate distance between some points so that I get a distance that is invariant to scale, translation, rotation. I read that I needed to compute normalized distance between points but I don't know how to do that. I looked on google but didn't get a mathematical formula. If someone could help me or at least give me tips to documentation to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate a normalized Euclidean distance between vectors **x**, **y** (from same distribution) with:

[image]

where **s** is a standard deviation of **x** and **y**. In general you can look at [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)

Comment: @OusGh I am at your service sir

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but it seems that this formula always returns a constant when I use it to compute distance between two points. I am really confused. I am looking for distance between two points that is invariant to scale and rotation but I can find any formula.

Comment: please paste an example, it is hard to guess what you are referring to

Comment: public static double MinusX(Vector3DF p1, Vector3DF p2)
        {
            return (p1.X - p2.X) * (p1.X - p2.X);
        }

        public static double MinusY(Vector3DF p1, Vector3DF p2)
        {
            return (p1.Y - p2.Y) * (p1.Y - p2.Y);
        }
        public static double MinusZ(Vector3DF p1, Vector3DF p2)
        {
            return (p1.Z - p2.Z) * (p1.Z - p2.Z);
        }

These funcions I use to substract x,y,z of the two points

Comment: public static double MahanalobisDistance(Vector3DF p1, Vector3DF p2)
        {
            double[] xVector = new double[] { p1.X, p2.X };
            double[] yVector = new double[] { p1.Y, p2.Y };
            double[] zVector = new double[] { p1.Z, p2.Z };


            double dist = Math.Abs((MinusX(p1, p2) / StandardDerivation(xVector)) + (MinusY(p1, p2)/StandardDerivation(yVector)) + (MinusZ(p1, p2)/ StandardDerivation(zVector)));

            return dist;
        }   this returns a constant = 6 no matter the two points I enter (inner eyes corner, outer eyes corner, nose length point)